# Trying to add a preorder traversal method to my class

Tags: python

```
class node:
    def __init__(self,value=None):
        self.value=value
        self.left_child=None
        self.right_child=None
        self.parent=None 

class binary_search_tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=None
    def insert(self,value):
        if self.root==None:
            self.root=node(value)
        else:
            self._insert(value,self.root)

    def _insert(self,value,cur_node):
        if value<cur_node.value:
            if cur_node.left_child==None:
                cur_node.left_child=node(value)
                cur_node.left_child.parent=cur_node 
            else:
                self._insert(value,cur_node.left_child)
        elif value>cur_node.value:
            if cur_node.right_child==None:
                cur_node.right_child=node(value)
                cur_node.right_child.parent=cur_node 
            else:
                self._insert(value,cur_node.right_child)
        else:
            print("Value already in tree!")

    def print_tree(self):
        if self.root!=None:
            self._print_tree(self.root)

    def _print_tree(self,cur_node):
        if cur_node!=None:
            self._print_tree(cur_node.left_child)
            print (str(cur_node.value))
            self._print_tree(cur_node.right_child)

    def height(self):
        if self.root!=None:
            return self._height(self.root,0)
        else:
            return 0

    def _height(self,cur_node,cur_height):
        if cur_node==None: return cur_height
        left_height=self._height(cur_node.left_child,cur_height+1)
        right_height=self._height(cur_node.right_child,cur_height+1)
        return max(left_height,right_height)

    def find(self,value):
        if self.root!=None:
            return self._find(value,self.root)
        else:
            return None

    def _find(self,value,cur_node):
        if value==cur_node.value:
            return cur_node
        elif value<cur_node.value and cur_node.left_child!=None:
            return self._find(value,cur_node.left_child)
        elif value>cur_node.value and cur_node.right_child!=None:
            return self._find(value,cur_node.right_child)



    def preorder(self):
        print(self.value)
        if self.left_child:
            self.left_child.preorder()
        if self.right_child:
            self.right_child.preorder()


tree = binary_search_tree()
tree.insert(21)
tree.insert(26)
tree.insert(30)
tree.insert(9)
print(tree.preorder)
```

So I have this binary search tree class and it all works correctly, however I added a preorder traversal method inside of my class, and that is not working. Does anyone know how i could modify this method for it to work? I am looking for it to just print out the preorder list. Should I add the root or value as a parameter to the method? I am just looking to be able to get it to preorder traversal and just print it, thats all i really need.

Comment: Instead of "it is not working" can you give a better description of the current behavior?

Comment: Calling `self.left_child.preorder()` isn't going to work, because the two child attributes are `node` instances, which has no such method.  You have an apparently working inorder traversal already, in the form of `print_tree()` and `_print_tree()`, changing that to preorder would just be swapping two lines.

Comment: which two lines do i need to swap? @jason

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post.

Comment: In general you want to put as much behaviour into the node class as makes sense, and if you have a tree class at all it should basically just keep track of the root. You can use it for operations that need to modify which node instance is the root of the tree.

Answer (score 1):

Preorder would be just a matter of changing the order of statements in `_print_tree()`. Something like this:

```
def preorder(self):
    if self.root!=None:
        self._preorder(self.root)

def _preorder(self,cur_node):
    if cur_node!=None:
        print (str(cur_node.value))
        self._preorder(cur_node.left_child)
        self._preorder(cur_node.right_child)
```

And call it like `tree.preorder()`

I strongly recommend going through the theory or ordered tree traversal: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are mixing and matching two approaches to organizing the recursion.

Approach 1:

```
def _insert(self,value,cur_node):
    # skipping logic, until we get to a recursive call:
            self._insert(value,cur_node.left_child)
```

The general logic in here is that the recursive calls call back to *the same tree object*, but pass the information about which node is being operated on *as a parameter*. This keeps the logic out of the Node class, which is just plain data storage.

Approach 2:

```
def preorder(self):
    # the recursive calls look instead like this:
        self.left_child.preorder()
```

This attempts to implement the recursion by *delegating to the node instances*, which requires them to have the behaviour. This whole block of code makes sense as a node method, since it is the nodes that have `left_child` and `right_child` attributes (that can be accessed from `self`). If you want to take this approach, then that code goes in the `node` class, and then in the `binary_search_tree` you would just need to delegate to the root node:

```
def preorder(self):
    self.root.preorder()
```

Either way, it is better if you pick one approach and stick with it: either

- have the tree class delegate to the root node, and give the nodes the needed functionality to do the recursion; or
- have the tree class handle the entire recursion, by keeping track of the "current" node. (You can also easily convert this approach to iteration.)

Answer (score 0):

```
def preorder(self):
    currentNode = self
    if currentNode is not None:
        print(currentNode.value)
        if currentNode.left:
            currentNode.left.preorder()
        if currentNode.right:
            currentNode.right.preorder()
```

try this